# Edge echo webrtc

Tags: webrtc, microsoft-edge, aec

I currently trying to get Edge working. With our Janus webrtc server. The video works fine, only the audio suffers a lot of echo and makes a conversation impossible.

Tried to set the getUserMedia audio constrains but it didn't help

```
audio: {
    echoCancellation: true,
    autoGainControl: true,
    noiseSuppression: true
}
```

Does anybody have a solution?

**Update 21-11-18:**

Results of the fiddle of @jib
[image]
I also created a screenshot from [MediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints)
[image]

Based on the 2 previous examples you would say echo cancelation is not working on Edge. But I noticed on [appear.in](https://appear.in/user) on there free version echo cancelation is working. I've tested between Edge and Chrome. As far as I understand appear.in free version uses peer connection (mesh) and not a server in between. As we are doing with Janus webrtc server.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [initial announcement](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/13/announcing-media-capture-functionality-in-microsoft-edge/) `echoCancellation` is a "missing feature" in Edge. A quick look in their [issue tracker](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/) did not reveal any open issues.

You can verify whether it is working by clicking the "Result" tab in [this blog](https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/fiddle-of-the-week-audio-constraints/).